# Insert Form Textbox value into next free cell

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm very new to VBA in excel, and I'm using it to communicate with an MySQL db to populate a budgeting sheet.
I've built a very simple form which fetch's the data, like this:

[image: UserForm]

This form will be used to fetch the desired product and then print its specs into the worksheet, like this:

[image: Insert data]

As you can see, I get the data from the MySQL into the ListView and then the selected row into 2 TextBoxs. But the 2 values are not printing in the right locations as its obvious in the picture. I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub Print_Values_Click()

If Select_prod.Value = "" Or Select_quant.Value = "" Then
If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you wan to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If

Dim LastRow As Long
 
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1")

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Select_prod.Value
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Select_quant.Value
 
End With
End Sub
```

So, not only is not printing the values where it should, its creating a new column (its supposed to be only 2) and prints in the same spot every time (overwrites the existent values and do not go to the next empty cell/row).
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Put a `.` (dot) in front of `Range` and `Rpws`, else Excel will write the data into the Activesheet: `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Select_prod.Value`

Comment: @FunThomas Hi, thanks for the reply. I did what you told me to, but now it only prints one value and still creates a new column and after that, with a new input, it overwrites the existent value.

Comment: @FunThomas That's a good call, but the real issue is finding the last used row doesn't work as usual if ListObjects (formatted tables) are involved. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` doesn't find the last used row correctly because you use formatted tables (ListObjects). If you want to find the next free row in a formatted table you need to do it like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1") 
    With .ListObjects("Table1") 'make sure to adjust the table name here
        Dim NextFreeRow As Long
        NextFreeRow = .DataBodyRange(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    .Cells(NextFreeRow, "A").Value = Select_prod.Value
    .Cells(NextFreeRow, "B").Value = Select_quant.Value
End With
```

---

**Explanation why your approach did not work**
If you use this technique `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` on a worksheet with ListObjects it will not find the last used row (of data) but always the last row of the ListObject.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!!!
If you allow me to make a last minute question about this, how can you make this to print after a certain Cell, for example: I only whant to print values after A3;B3. Something like that. 
Thanks again!!

Comment: `If NextFreeRow < 4 Then NextFreeRow = 4` ensures that it starts at row 4 even if the `NextFreeRow` was less than 4